# Find value by Name in XmlNode Array

Tags: c#, asp.net, arrays, xml, xmlnode

I have the below XML:

```
<UserArea>
    <Property>
        <NameValue name="amperage" type="StringType">1</NameValue>
    </Property>
    <Property>
        <NameValue name="attachments" type="StringType">2</NameValue>
    </Property>
    <Property>
        <NameValue name="noOfBolts" type="StringType">3</NameValue>
    </Property>
    <Property>
        <NameValue name="boreSize" type="StringType">4</NameValue>
    </Property>
</UserArea>
```

This XML I am getting in `XmlNode[]` and I need the all the properties by Name, I have tried below things:

```
      var xmlNodeArray = (XmlNode[])item.UserArea; //get xmlNode Array 
      var attachments = xmlNodeArray.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Name == "attachments")?.InnerText; //Not working, always returning null value
      foreach (var xmlNode in xmlNodeArray)
      {
           var val = xmlNode["attachments"]?.InnerText; // Not working
           var data = xmlNode.InnerText; // working but need to looping
      }
```

I have around 250 Property elements so I don't want to use `foreach` here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can easily do it using [Xml.Linq](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/linq/linq-to-xml-overview). Parse your xml into [`XDocument`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.xml.linq.xdocument?view=netframework-4.8), then go through `Root` descendants and get a value of first element, whose `name` attribute equals *attachments* value

```cs
var document = XDocument.Parse(xml);
var result =
    document.Root?.Descendants()
        .FirstOrDefault(e => e.HasAttributes && e.Attribute("name")?.Value == "attachments")?.Value ??
        string.Empty;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can always select nodes using XPath

```
XmlNodeList nodes = userAreaNode.SelectNodes("//Property/NameValue[@name='attachments']");
```

Comment: It should be //Property/NameValue[@name='attachments'] as the name attribute is on the NameValue element.

Comment: Also to add, if you can guarantee there will only ever be one instance of each NameValue you can use SelectSingleNode instead to return a single XmlNode.